# SQL Stuck with query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am Creating a database and I have 3 tables. A volunteer Table and an Event table. I created an EventVolunteer table which was the result of a many to many relationship.The fields in each Table are:

**Event Table**

```
Event 
EventID 
Event_Name 
Event_Location 
Starting_Point 
Ending_Point
```

**Volunteer Table**

```
Volunteer 
VolunteerID 
Volunteer_FName 
Volunteer_LName 
Volunteer_Age 
Volunteer_Email_Address 
First_Aid
```

**EventVolunteer Table**

```
EventVolunteer
EventID
Volunteer ID
```

The eventVolunteer is currently displaying all event ids and all volunteerids

some volunteers First_Aid fields are set to yes and some are set to no.

I need a query that displays all volunteers that are on an event that have first aid, the first aid values are set to either yes or no.

Comment: Based on your requirement "... that are on an event with first aid" I would think that `first_aid` is an attribute of `EventTable`, not `VolunteerTable`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague.  My assumptions is as follow:  You would like to get a list of all volunteers that have first aid skills (where Volunteer.First_Aid = yes) and have registered for an event. You want returned the volunteer details as well as the event they registered for.  You can use the following query:

```
SELECT v.*, e.*
FROM
    Volunteer v
    INNER JOIN EventVolunteer ev
        ON v.Volunteer_ID = ev.Volunteer_ID
    INNER JOIN Event e
        ON ev.EventID = e.EventID
WHERE
    v.First_Aid = 'Yes'
```

If you had a different result in mind, please add more detail to your question.

Marius

Comment: Hi Marius thank you everything in the query worked besides my where clause, not too sure why, The data type for First_Aid is varchar(3) and its either a yes or a no however it doesn't seem to be working, I made sure I was case-sensitive too, any ideas? thank you!

Comment: Hmmm.  Not sure.  Just to make sure case-sensitivity is not the issue, try replacing my where clause with UPPER(v.First_Aid) = 'Yes'    If that does not work, can you please attached a sample of your output.  That might assist.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to join the tables, and then use a WHERE clause to find your values.

You can substitute * for what fields you want

```
SELECT * 
FROM EventVolunteer AS ev
INNER JOIN Event AS e
    ON ev.EventID = e.EventID
INNER JOIN Volunteer AS v
    ON ev.VolunteerID = v.VolunteerID
WHERE v.First_Aid = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from volunteer t
join event_volunteer t2 on t.volunteer_id=t2.volunteer_id
where t.first_aid = true //if it's boolean
```